# Where can I find actual official documentation for bitcoin.conf?

Tags: bitcoin.conf, documentation

As in title, where is actual bitcoin.conf docs?

Protocol is evolving, and many articles are not accurate regarding do bitcoin.conf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example bitcoin.conf file for the current Bitcoin Core version (25.0 at time of writing) is [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/25.x/share/examples/bitcoin.conf) and a tool for helping you generate a config file is [here](https://jlopp.github.io/bitcoin-core-config-generator/).